# IE10 not using correct priority for max-width and min-width

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I'm creating a responsive website and want images to take up at most 2/3 of their column, but not be smaller than 300px wide (or larger than the original image width).

I'm using the following CSS:

`img {max-width:66%;min-width:300px;}`

In Chrome + Firefox, this works perfectly - starting from very wide, the image displays at its uploaded size; then when that is 2/3 of the column, it starts shrinking until it hits 300px, then doesn't shrink any further.

In IE10, the image continues to shrink past 300px - it ignores 300px altogether.

Is there any way IE10 can understand that min-width should take priority?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WHDsm/3/

Note that using something like width:66% isn't an option, since then there is no way of saying 'don't display larger than uploaded'.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to set `max-width` in this case, just `width`.

```
img {
    width: 66%; 
    min-width:300px;
}
```

works in IE10: http://jsfiddle.net/WHDsm/9/

> "Note that using something like width:66% isn't an option, since then
>   there is no way of saying 'don't display larger than uploaded'."

There's a bit of a logic issue here as well.  `max-width` and `min-width` are usually meant as overrides to `width` in instances where responsive layout is being used to ensure the elements do not exceed or precede a fixed dimension which the user defines.  Saying an element can never exceed a certain percentage is bad form because the percentage is constant in ratio to it's parent element.  It will always be 66% of its parent element--unless you have `min/max` defined.

Setting `width: 66%; max-width: 1000px; min-width 300px;` gives you a range of values based on the parent container when `66%` of that parent container is between 300px and 1000px.  Ergo, if your user can not upload an image larger than `width: 1000px;`, then the image will never expand beyond 1000px and you will not see any issues with image quality.

Comment: max-width as a percentage is extremely common and in fact almost always used with a max-width of 100%. Setting a width to a fixed percentage really makes no sense as I mentioned - it means you give the user absolutely no control over what size images display; you're forcing them all to display at exactly the same width, whereas the norm is to display them at the uploaded size when possible. According to the official CSS specs, min-width should take priority over max-width, so the bug is in IE10.